# Can you get bukkit in 1.8 minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

have they made bukkit for 1.8 Minecraft yet?

Comment: they made it ages ago if you had the 1.7.10 version already they had a patch, however the site is not letting you download bukkit due to a takedown request

Answer (score 1):

the official site is currently not allowing you to download craftbukkit because of a [DMCA takedown request](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206000441/http://dl.bukkit.org/dmca/notification.txt).

Answer (score 1):

**No, the offical developers have not and will not**, but there is another solution. The offical developers of CraftBukkit have not continued because of a [DMCA takedown request](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206000441/http://dl.bukkit.org/dmca/notification.txt). **However**, good news is that the developers of [SpigotMC](https://www.spigotmc.org/) have continued both their project, their API and Bukkit(both the API and CraftBukkit). To build these, you use BuildTools, and the wiki is here: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/. Unfortunately, it may be a little more advanced for non-tech-savvy people, but on Windows, the basic gist is:

1. Get prerequisites(Git and Java)
2. Right click on `BuildTools.jar` and click `Git Bash`.
3. Run `java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev (version)` and replace version with the Minecraft version you want. For example, `java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.8.9` **Don't double click on the jar.**
4. Wait a few minutes. The jars are being compiled.
5. When done, you will find `craftbukkit-(version).jar` and `spigot-(version).jar`. These are the server jars! Use `craftbukkit-(version).jar` if you want to use CraftBukkit, or `spigot-(version).jar` if you want to use... well, Spigot!